# Image of linear operator is dense (proof)

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Suppose that $H$ is an inner product space and let $T: H \longrightarrow$ H be a linear operator. Show that, if for every $x \in X$, there exists a $c>0$ such that

$$
\langle Tx , x \rangle \geq c\|x\|^2
$$
then $\text{Im}T$ is dense.

**Discussion:**

A short proof is using a theorem which states that $D \subset H$ is dense if $D^\perp = \{0\}$, which is obviously true in this case.

However, I seek for a more *"analytic"* approach, if there is one.

**Thoughts:**

Let $x \in H$. Then

$$
\lambda = \frac{\langle Tx , x \rangle}{\|x\|^2}
$$

is the magnitude of the orthogonal projection of $Tx$ along $x$. Then, for every $x \in H$, there exists a $c > 0$ such that
$$
\lambda  \geq c
$$

Also, applying the pythagorean theorem:

$$
\|Tx - \lambda x\|^2 = \|Tx\|^2 - \lambda \|x\|^2 \leq \|Tx\|^2 - c \|x\|^2
$$

Is this approach at all close to showing that, for every $\varepsilon > 0$

$$
\|Tx-x\| < \varepsilon
$$

Comment: Is $c$ independent of $x$?  Your 2nd sentence says otherwise.